# Example of an URL for a node.js code

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

. Given the following node.js code answer the questions below it: 
What is the URL of this Endpoint if the domain is http://example.com?

```
router.route('/getOrders')
.get(function(req, res){
 res.locals.session = req.session;
db.getOrders(req.session.email, function (err, orderList) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should read router express document in [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router)

```
router
    .get('/getOrders', function (req, res, next) {
        // in here when you request http:/example.com/getOrders
    })
    .get('/getOrders/:id_or_anything_else', function (req, res, next) {
        // in here when you request http:/example.com/getOrders/Order_detail
        console.log(req.params.id_or_anything_else)
    })
;

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: really! I thought it was http:/example.com/getOrders/Order_detail

Comment: router.route('/getOrders')
     .get(function(req, res){
     res.locals.session = req.session;
 db.getOrders(req.session.email, function (err, orderList) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
res.json('order_detail', 
 { message: [{desc: "Could not retrieve order details", type: "error"}]});
  } else {
   res.json('order_detail', {
   'orders' : orderList

Comment: you should check router express document again.